# Resize the parent's height of an iFrame based on its height

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I am trying to resize the div height based on the height of the iframe. When the iframe is loaded the function resizeIframe is triggered. However, I the output in the console log does not represent the real height of the iframe. I get 67px in the console, but the iframe is more than 2000px long.

What am I missing in this case?

```
<div class="text-base" id="iframe-parent" style="height: 1200px;">
    <iframe onload="resizeIframe(this)" frameborder="0" height="100%" src="https://www.example.com"</iframe>
</div>


<script>
var iframeHeight = 0
function resizeIframe(iframe) {
    iframeHeight = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
    console.log(iframeHeight)
    document.getElementById('iframe-parent').style.height = iframeHeight;
}
</script>
```

Comment: First of all you are missing, that these `src=“https://www.example.com“` are not the correct quotes to use as attribute delimiters in HTML. The browser will see this as a _relative_ URL, that it completes with your base URL - so it will request something like `http(s)://yourdomain. com/“https://www.example.com“`, which is not what you wanted to begin with.

Comment: And once you fixed that, and make it _actually_ load an external URL into the iframe, the browser console will be able to tell you what the problem is. (You should be getting an error saying something like, _"Blocked a frame with origin [...] from accessing a cross-origin frame."_ If you don't know what that error means - please go research it.)